# How to enable support for m:oMathPara in docx4j

Tags: java, xslt, xhtml, docx4j, omml

I'm trying to convert a docx file, which contains an equation in it, to html, but when doing so, while it renders everything else correctly, for the equation it prints:

NOT IMPLEMENTED: support for m:oMath -

Is there any way to get docx4j to provide html that can display equations?

Comment: Well, there is MathML, obviously...

Answer (score 0):

Where do your equations come from?

There is MathML, and Microsoft's OMML.

MathML can be converted to OMML (for insertion into docx/pptx/xlsx) via Microsoft's mathml2omml.xsl (included in Microsoft Office installations).

Conversely, there is omml2mml.xsl

If you can use MathML as your source format, then (with a little integration work, perhaps), that MathML could be rendered as SVG.

If your equations are in OMML format, you'd need to convert to MathML first.  Try omml2mml.xsl and see also http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/xhtml-and-mathml-from-office-20007.html